# ERC20 Transaction failing due to invalid nonce value

Tags: web3js, javascript, nodejs, ethereumjs

I am trying to send an erc20 transaction but I keep getting an error telling me that the account I'm sending the transaction from has a nonce value of 1 while the tx has a nonce value of 31613. I am running ganache-cli on the terminal and compiled + deployed my smart contract using the remix IDE by connecting to a web3 provider on my localhost. Account 1 and Account 2 are accounts from the 10 generated by ganache. I made sure to make the sending address the first account from the 10 because it is the one that contains the initial supply of tokens. I do not know where the problem with the nonce value occurs can someone point me to the right direction?

This is the code that sends the transaction:

```
var Web3 = require('web3')
var fs = require('fs')
const Tx = require('ethereumjs-tx').Transaction

var web3 = web3 ? new Web3(web3.currentProvider) : new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));

var txHash
var senderAddress
var receiverAddress

var contractAddress = "0x687c065c7a2b5711b9a651c13d9b51f5db71451d" //Ethereum contract address
var abiArray = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('tixtokenabi.json', 'utf-8')) //abi of contract
var contract = new web3.eth.Contract(abiArray, contractAddress) //Smart Contract instance 

var rawTransaction = {
    "from": account1,
    "nonce": web3.utils.toHex(web3.eth.getTransactionCount(account1)),
    "gasPrice": web3.utils.toHex(web3.eth.gasPrice),
    "gasLimit": web3.utils.toHex(90000),
    "to": contractAddress,
    "value": "0x0",
    "data": contract.methods.transfer(account2, amount).encodeABI(),
    "chainId": "0x01"
  };

  var privKey = new Buffer(private_key, 'hex')
  var tx = new Tx(rawTransaction)
  tx.sign(privKey)
  var serializedTx = tx.serialize()

  web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction('0x' + serializedTx.toString('hex'), function (err, hash) {

    //if transaction goes through
    if (!err) {

      console.log("Transaction successful! redirecting...")

      //Get transaction hash
      console.log(hash)
      setTxHash(hash)

      //Get balances of two accounts
      var balance1 = contract.methods.balanceOf(account1).send()
      var balance2 = contract.methods.balanceOf(account2).send()

      return {
        balance1:balance1,
        balance2:balance2
      }

      //if transaction fails
    } else { 
      console.log("Error! Transaction failed..")
      console.log(err)
    }   
  });
```

And here is the error log:

```
Error! Transaction failed..
Error: Returned error: the tx doesn't have the correct nonce. account has nonce of: 1 tx has nonce of: 31613
    at Object.ErrorResponse (/home/zein/node_modules/web3-core-helpers/src/errors.js:29:16) 
    at /home/zein/node_modules/web3-core-requestmanager/src/index.js:140:36
    at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (/home/zein/node_modules/web3-providers-http/src/index.js:110:13)
    at XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.dispatchEvent (/home/zein/node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request-event-target.js:34:22)
    at XMLHttpRequest._setReadyState (/home/zein/node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request.js:208:14)
    at XMLHttpRequest._onHttpResponseEnd (/home/zein/node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request.js:318:14)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/home/zein/node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request.js:289:61)
    at emitNone (events.js:111:20)
    at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (/home/zein/node_modules/web3-providers-http/src/index.js:110:13)
    at XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.dispatchEvent (/home/zein/node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request-event-target.js:34:22)
    at XMLHttpRequest._setReadyState (/home/zein/node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request.js:208:14)
    at XMLHttpRequest._onHttpResponseEnd (/home/zein/node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request.js:318:14)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/home/zein/node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request.js:289:61)
    at emitNone (events.js:111:20)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:208:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1064:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function `web3.eth.getTransactionCount` returns a promise, which you need to resolve.

Hence you are using this function incorrectly here:

```
"nonce": web3.utils.toHex(web3.eth.getTransactionCount(account1))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can encounter this same error in ethersjs.

As of ethers v6, you can get the required nonce using the [getNonce](https://docs.ethers.org/v6/api/providers/#Signer-getNonce) method on your signer.

```
const wallet = new ethers.Wallet(
    address,
    provider
  );

const nonce = await wallet.getNonce();

const contract = await contractFactory.deploy(
    {   
        nonce: nonce,
        gasLimit: 1000000,
        gasPrice: 2000000000,
        value: 0,
    }
  );
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to put next value of nonce
Try this it will work

> let myNonce =await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(_toAddress)  let
> NetxNonce= web3.utils.toHex(myNonce++)